# Categorizing data based on the value of a field

Tags: sql

I have a table like:

```
userid    cityid
1         4
1         5
2         4
2         1
3         1
3         5
```

Is there a way in SQL or hive to transform it into a table like:

```
userid    city1    city4   city5
1         false    true    true
2         true     true    fase
3         true     false   true
```

I am not sure there is a word to describe this kind of operation...
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You could probably handle that with PIVOT (assuming that the ID's aren't fixed to just 1, 4, 5). For SQL Server see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx. Some people might also refer to the result you are seeking as a crosstab.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is basically a `PIVOT`. You did not specify what RDBMS you are using but you can use an aggregate function and a `CASE` statement to get the results in any DB:

```
select userid,
  max(case when cityid = 1 then 'true' else 'false' end) city1,
  max(case when cityid = 2 then 'true' else 'false' end) city2,
  max(case when cityid = 3 then 'true' else 'false' end) city3,
  max(case when cityid = 4 then 'true' else 'false' end) city4,
  max(case when cityid = 5 then 'true' else 'false' end) city5
from yourtable
group by userid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b18c/9)

Results:

```
| USERID | CITY1 | CITY2 | CITY3 | CITY4 | CITY5 |
--------------------------------------------------
|      1 | false | false | false |  true |  true |
|      2 |  true | false | false |  true | false |
|      3 |  true | false | false | false |  true |
```